# Fix columns in horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to fix my first column in a table when the user scrolls in the X-axis.
I am using this structure:

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table id="consumption-data" class="data">
        <thead class="header">
            <tr>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Item 1</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="results">
            <tr>
                <th>Jan</th>
                <td>3163</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feb</th>
                <td>3163.7</td>         
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Mar</th>
                <td>3163.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Apr</th>
                <td>3163.7</td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <th>May</th>
                <td>3163.7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Jun</th>
                <td>3163.7</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>...</th>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The number of items will be picked by the user, i.e. it could be 90 items in the table. This will require scrolling in the X-axis. The question I have got though is:

How do I fix the position of the `th` tags inside the `tbody` (and the `th:first-child` in the `thead`)?

I have been looking at some other threads, however they do not really explain how I achieve the fixed columns which makes it hard for me to understand what the codes does and what I am supposed to do.

I have also checked on solutions where people split up the header-column in another table. This wont be possible for me because I will export the data to other systems later on.

My css:

```
.table-wrapper { 
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:visible;
}
```

This fixes the scroll, now comes the work with:

```
tbody th, 
thead th:first-child {}
```

Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT: Here is a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DJqPf/5/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**SOLVED**

https://jsfiddle.net/DJqPf/7/

```
.table-wrapper { 
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:visible;
    width:250px;
    margin-left: 120px;
}
td, th {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
th:first-child {
    position: fixed;
    left: 5px
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

```js
$(function () {  
  $('.table-wrapper tr').each(function () {
    var tr = $(this),
        h = 0;
    tr.children().each(function () {
      var td = $(this),
          tdh = td.height();
      if (tdh > h) h = tdh;
    });
    tr.css({height: h + 'px'});
  });
});
```

```css
body {
    position: relative;
}
.table-wrapper { 
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:visible;
    width:200px;
    margin-left: 120px;
}


td, th {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
tbody tr {
  
}
th:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>SOME RANDOM TEXT</h1>
</div>
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table id="consumption-data" class="data">
        <thead class="header">
            <tr>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Item 1</th>
                <th>Item 2</th>
                <th>Item 3</th>
                <th>Item 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="results">
            <tr>
                <th>Jan is an awesome month</th>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Feb</th>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Mar</th>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Apr</th>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <th>May</th>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Jun</th>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
                <td>3163</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>...</th>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see that the jsFiddle does what i want, but could you please explain what's happening?

Comment: There is also the problem with the positioning of this. When i implement this solution to my code the th's is being stacked above each other and being fixed outside of my container

Comment: I can't tell whats wrong with a code I can't see. Maybe adding a width to your th:first-child rule will  fix your problem but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Didnt help. Allthough i messed around with the positioning instead: Made another wrapper and gave it a relative positioning, then added position: absolute; to th:first-child. Seems to work :)

Comment: Thanks I wanted this only :) but can you do one more thing with scroll up thead also when we scroll up.???

Comment: Will do it ... in the meantime you can check this one with a check box http://jsbin.com/IwisANaX/2

Comment: Works only if only one table exist in whole page which is not the practical use case. First column is fixed vertically as well which is not desired.

Comment: I do not get it @kushdilip ... can u show me an example?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto open this http://jsfiddle.net/08eog7n9/ and try scrolling vertically. first column stays there.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto Yup, that's exactly how I solved it too. but there is one more issue I am facing. look at http://jsfiddle.net/08eog7n9/4/.
the text in first column is wrapping and making the the cell height grow but other cells in the same row are not growing along. I don't want to use `white-space:nowrap;` , I want the wrapping feature.

Comment: not a pretty solution but http://jsbin.com/lufaloluhi/1/edit?css,output `tbody tr:first-child {  height: 65px; }` does the job

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto you are harcoding the height here which cannot be solution.. I found a working solution for this problem which involves minimal JavaScript . I'll post that soon.

Comment: @kushdilip did you have JavaScript solution?

Comment: @SergeyKharchishin I added the JS solution for the table first column height problem in the answer UPDATE.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto : In first column i have dynamic data. so i can't set height explicitly. How would i handle that scenario when i don't how much content i will have for first column

Comment: If you want to break lines than you need a new question, otherwise you can use `white-space: nowrap;` and a fixed height.

Comment: Please provide come explanation

Comment: The code is very simple and you should be able to understand it @csharpsql. But to make it simple here is the relevant part:
in the css, `th:first-child` `position` is `absolute` and the `table-wrapper` `margin-left` moves the table to the proper place; In the js, all `tr` heights are set equal to their highest child.

Comment: Your first example makes no sense - you can freely remove it from your answer. As soon as the document gets vertical scrollbars your fixed elements are fixed to viewport - not to the table. (or use `absolute` instead ;) )

Comment: it's a simplified version, so people can understand what's going on ;D

Comment: can you freeze the header of the table as well?

Comment: sure, you can use the same method!

Comment: This approach has an issue. 
If the full page is vertical scrollable. The fixed column will move with the page scoll @rafaelcastrocouto

Comment: Please read all the comments @RohitKumar ... this issue has already been adressed

Answer (score 5):

Solved using JavaScript + jQuery!
I just need similar solution to my project but current solution with HTML and CSS is not ok for me because there is issue with column height + I need more then one column to be fixed. So I create simple javascript solution using jQuery

You can try it here
https://jsfiddle.net/kindrosker/ffwqvntj/

All you need is setup home many columsn will be fixed in 
data-count-fixed-columns parameter

```
<table class="table" data-count-fixed-columns="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

and run js function

```
app_handle_listing_horisontal_scroll($('#table-listing'))
```

Comment: Well, i guess that if you have to opportunity to wait for jQuery.ready() you could do this as well. There should be ways of doing this with CSS also however. Thx for your input!

Comment: @Jari Thorup Palo, yes your are right, with long table we have to wait document ready $(function(){ ... }). About CSS the previous solution will work for table with fixed Width/Height cell.

Comment: Is there a way to fix table header too?

Answer (score 2):

Demo: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer/

HTML

```
<h2>TableHeadFixer Fix Left Column</h2>

<div id="parent">
    <table id="fixTable" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Ano</th>
                <th>Jan</th>
                <th>Fev</th>
                <th>Mar</th>
                <th>Abr</th>
                <th>Maio</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>2012</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>550.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2012</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>550.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2012</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>550.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2012</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>550.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2012</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>110.00</td>
                <td>550.00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fixTable").tableHeadFixer({"head" : false, "right" : 1}); 
    });
```

CSS

```
    #parent {
        height: 300px;
    }

    #fixTable {
        width: 1800px !important;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5gfuqqc4/

Comment: Using javascript for this is a viable solution as long as your table doesn't have big loads of data in it. If your table is too big, use CSS instead as this has got much better performance.

When i wrote this question three years ago my data table had one row of input for each seconds in at least one year, and was intended for use in comparison of at least 10 columns. Imagine iterating through that with jQuery. :) Thanks for your input!