# Fix first column of multiple tables overlapping each other

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<div class="parent-class">
 <div class="div1" style="z-index:1;">
    <table>
  <tr>
   <td>fixed column</td>
   <td>simple column</td>
   <td>simple column</td>
   <td>fsimple column</td>
   <td>simple column</td>
   <td>simple column</td>
  </tr>
  ......
  ......
 </table>
 </div>
 
  <div class="div2" style="z-index:2;">
    <table>
  <tr>
   <td>fixed column</td>
   <td>simple column</td>
   <td>simple column</td>
   <td>fsimple column</td>
   <td>simple column</td>
   <td>simple column</td>
  </tr>
  ......
  ......
 </table>
 </div>
  <div class="div3" style="z-index:3;">
    <table>
  <tr>
   <td>fixed column</td>
   <td>simple column</td>
   <td>simple column</td>
   <td>fsimple column</td>
   <td>simple column</td>
   <td>simple column</td>
  </tr>
  ......
  ......
 </table>
 </div>
 
 </div>
```

As you can see all three tables are overlapping each other and working fine but I am not able to fix that first column of my tables on horizontal scrolling.
Please help me to fix this by some CSS code.

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: its a library so i can't make same fiddle but i have pasted the core structure in my ques

Comment: you want the first column to be fixed?
Why not trying

`tr > td:first-child {
position:fixed;
}` ?

Comment: Duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826775/fix-columns-in-horizontal-scrolling