# Vertical - Horizontal Scrolling HTML Table with fixed columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a html table with vertical and Horizontal scrolling.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

});
</script>
<style>
div #sample.tableContainer {
    clear: both;
    height: 360px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
}
/* define width of table. Add 16px to width for scrollbar.           */
 html>body div.tableContainer table {
    width: 600px;
}
html>body thead.fixedHeader tr {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 17px;
}

thead.fixedHeader th {
    background: #C96;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid;
    min-width:100px;


}
thead.fixedHeader {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid;

}
html>body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    border:1px solid;
}
tbody.scrollContent td, tbody.scrollContent tr.normalRow td {
    border:1px solid;
    min-width:100px;
}
tbody.scrollContent tr.alternateRow td {
    border:1px solid;
}
html>body thead.fixedHeader th {
    width: 60px;
}
html>body tbody.scrollContent td {
    width: 60px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="sample" class="fixedColumns" style="width=600px;overflow:auto">
<table style="font-size:13px" id="data"  cellpadding="2" class="scrollTable">
    <thead style="background:#e2e2e2" align="center" class="fixedHeader">
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
            <th>Header 5</th>
            <th>Header 6</th>
            <th>Header 7</th>
            <th>Header 8</th>
            <th>Header 9</th>
            <th>Header 10</th>
            <th>Header 11</th>
            <th>Header 12</th>
            <th>Header 13</th>
            <th>Header 14</th>
            <th>Header 15</th>
            <th>Header 16</th>
            <th>Header 17</th>
            <th>Header 18</th>
            <th>Header 19</th>
            <th>Header 20</th>
            <th>Header 21</th>
            <th>Header 22</th>
            <th>Header 23</th>
            <th>Header 24</th>
            <th>Header 25</th>
            <th>Header 26</th>
            <th>Header 27</th>
            <th>Header 28</th>
            <th>Header 29</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody align="center" class="scrollContent">
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
            <td>Data 9</td>
            <td>Data 10</td>
            <td>Data 11</td>
            <td>Data 12</td>
            <td>Data 13</td>
            <td>Data 14</td>
            <td>Data 15</td>
            <td>Data 16</td>
            <td>Data 17</td>
            <td>Data 18</td>
            <td>Data 19</td>
            <td>Data 20</td>
            <td>Data 21</td>
            <td>Data 22</td>
            <td>Data 23</td>
            <td>Data 24</td>
            <td>Data 25</td>
            <td>Data 26</td>
            <td>Data 27</td>
            <td>Data 28</td>
            <td>Data 29</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But with above html script how to achieve the fixing  of first five columns in table?
If I put something like this as below my vertical scrolling goes way off:

```
.fixedColumns  {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-left: 500px;
}

.fixedColumns > table > * > tr > th:nth-child(1),
.fixedColumns  > table > * > tr > td:nth-child(1){
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    margin-left: -500px;
}
```

Anybody has a solution/pointers on how to fix first 5 columns and have both vertical and horizontal scroll available?

Comment: How to achieve what fixing? You're going to have to be more specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix columns in horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826775/fix-columns-in-horizontal-scrolling)

Comment: @sauntimo that solution vertical scroll goes for a toss if you put a height to it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this guy has the solution @  http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-To-Freeze-Table-Columns-Rows-On-Scroll.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a really quick go at this by using `position: absolute` and offsetting with different amounts of `left` for different columns. You could develop this a bit and probably make something work. But, the conclusion I came to was that if I was doing this, I would consider

(a) having the fixed section as a different table element and constructing the mark up separately (I'm assuming you're using a function to build this mark up?)

(b) presenting your data differently - a table with that many columns is going to be really hard for anyone to actually use. Perhaps you don't need to see all the columns all the time? Perhaps you could present the data differently, say in collapsible sections or something - It's difficult to know what exactly to suggest given I don't know your use case, but I wouldn't want to have to use a table that wide for anything.

```css
#sample {
  position: static;
  clear: both;
  height: 360px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 540px;
}


/* define width of table. Add 16px to width for scrollbar.           */

html>body div.tableContainer table {
  width: 600px;
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader tr {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 17px;
}

thead.fixedHeader th {
  background: #C96;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  min-width: 100px;
}

thead.fixedHeader {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent {
  display: block;
  /* height: 200px; */
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid;
}

tbody.scrollContent td,
tbody.scrollContent tr.normalRow td {
  border: 1px solid;
  min-width: 100px;
}

tbody.scrollContent tr.alternateRow td {
  border: 1px solid;
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th {
  width: 60px;
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent td {
  width: 60px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #CCC
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #FFF
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
}

.abs.a_one{
  left: 0;
}

.abs.a_two {
  left: 110px;
}

.abs.a_three {
  left: 220px;
}

.abs.a_four {
  left: 330px;
}

.abs.a_five {
  left: 440px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sample" class="fixedColumns">
  <table style="font-size:13px" id="data" cellpadding="2" class="scrollTable">
    <thead style="background:#e2e2e2" align="center" class="fixedHeader">
      <tr>
        <th class="abs a_one">Header 1</th>
        <th class="abs a_two">Header 2</th>
        <th class="abs a_three">Header 3</th>
        <th class="abs a_four">Header 4</th>
        <th class="abs a_five">Header 5</th>
        <th>Header 6</th>
        <th>Header 7</th>
        <th>Header 8</th>
        <th>Header 9</th>
        <th>Header 10</th>
        <th>Header 11</th>
        <th>Header 12</th>
        <th>Header 13</th>
        <th>Header 14</th>
        <th>Header 15</th>
        <th>Header 16</th>
        <th>Header 17</th>
        <th>Header 18</th>
        <th>Header 19</th>
        <th>Header 20</th>
        <th>Header 21</th>
        <th>Header 22</th>
        <th>Header 23</th>
        <th>Header 24</th>
        <th>Header 25</th>
        <th>Header 26</th>
        <th>Header 27</th>
        <th>Header 28</th>
        <th>Header 29</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody align="center" class="scrollContent">
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="abs a_one">Data 1</td>
        <td class="abs a_two">Data 2</td>
        <td class="abs a_three">Data 3</td>
        <td class="abs a_four">Data 4</td>
        <td class="abs a_five">Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
        <td>Data 17</td>
        <td>Data 18</td>
        <td>Data 19</td>
        <td>Data 20</td>
        <td>Data 21</td>
        <td>Data 22</td>
        <td>Data 23</td>
        <td>Data 24</td>
        <td>Data 25</td>
        <td>Data 26</td>
        <td>Data 27</td>
        <td>Data 28</td>
        <td>Data 29</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying out, but it throws the horizontal row alignment and fixed header off the grid.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean there. Good luck though! You might be able to do something with `position: absolute` that could work.