# Lock a column with CSS

Tags: html, css, cell

Edit: I tried the solution that was recommended in the topic that this post may have been a duplicate of.  Copy and pasted the solution from jsfiddle.net/DJqPf/7/ into john.nichel.net/test2.html (I don't have enough rep to post two links so I can't give you the http) and it doesn't scroll at all.

I'm looking to lock one or two columns of data in a table or div using CSS, meaning that other columns scroll but the locked ones do not.

I've tried a few jQuery plugins and many of the CSS/div examples I've found but, for whatever reason, I can't make the unlocked columns start after the locked one.  I've tried positions like absolute, fixed, relative, etc., but can't seem to get these examples to work. How can I achieve this?

The code below is also at http://john.nichel.net/test.html so you can see how the locked column is displayed over the other columns.  I'm going to keep working on this, so the code on my site will probably be different than what I've posted below.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.header {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rowGroup {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cell_locked {
  position: absolute;
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div style="overflow-x:auto;width:770px;overflow:scroll;">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="cell_locked">Test Lock</div>
        <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 1</div>
        <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 2</div>
        <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 3</div>
        <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 4</div>
        <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 5</div>
        <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 6</div>
        <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 7</div>
        <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 8</div>
        <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 9</div>
        <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 10</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

Comment: What does "locking a column" mean? Freeze like Excel spreadsheet where the other columns scroll but frozen columns doesn't ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix columns in horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826775/fix-columns-in-horizontal-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sollution for this. You can make two tables instead of one. First table has on column with those locked cells, the second one is fixed to the first one and it containes all those scrollables rows. The only thing you should do is position those two tables so that thay look as one element. And here for some reasons I don't fully understand you have to pack both your tables into another div and give it artibite display: flex, this is something I don't fully understand, I mean the value of the atribute.
Here is code:

```
<!--Container for both tables-->
<div class="container">
<!--first table -locked-->
    <div class="table">
        <div class="rowGroup">
            <div class="cell_locked">Test Lock</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowGroup">
            <div class="cell_locked">Test Lock</div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--second table -scrollable -->
    <div class="table" style="overflow-x:auto;width:770px;overflow:scroll;">
        <div class="rowGroup">
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 1</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 2</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 3</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 4</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 5</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 6</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 7</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 8</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 9</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="header">
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 1</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 2</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 3</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 4</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 5</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 6</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 7</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 8</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 9</div>
                <div class="cell">Unlocked Cell 10</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in styles:

```
.container
{
    display: flex;
}
```

Now you have all those scrolable elements in one scrollable div so there is only one scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  I tried this, and it worked for the single row, but when I add multiple rows, it doesn't freeze the first column, and if I wrap those new rows like the first one, I get a scroll bar for each row (first cell is frozen though).

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry I haven't thought about it but I think I got a different sollution which should be more scalable.

Comment: I edited my answer so now it should work for multiple rows.