# How to fix/freeze first three columns in a table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am currently using bootstrap. I have a table which has many columns. I want to fix the first three columns of the table with defined width and make the table scroll horizontally. I have 12 columns and would like to set their width manually in order to represent the data better. The table looks like follows:-

```
+-----+---------+-------------------+------------------+----------+---------
| No. |   Id    |      Address      | Numeric Category | Image 1  | Image 2 | Image 3 | Image 4  | Coordinates |  |  |  |
+-----+---------+-------------------+------------------+----------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+--+--+--+
|   1 |     121 | 123, Ring Road    | A                |          |         |         |          |             |  |  |  |
|   2 |     122 |  123, Ring Road   | B                |          |         |         |          |             |  |  |  |
|   3 |    322  | 123, Ring Road    |A                 |          |         |         |          |             |  |  |  |
|   4 |     222 | 123, Ring Road    |                  |          |         |         |          |             |  |  |  |
|   5 |    212  | 123, Ring Road    |                  |          |         |         |          |             |  |  |  |
+-----+---------+-------------------+------------------+----------+---------+---------+----------+-------------+--+--+--+
```

Table Code:-

```
<table class="table table-xxs">
    <thead>
        <tr class="active">
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>Response Id</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Image 1</th>
            <th>Image 2</th>
            <th>Image 3</th>
            <th>Image 4</th>
            <th>Coordinates</th>
        </tr>                               
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have little knowledge of css or javascript. As i mentioned before i am using bootstrap theme. I want to scroll the table horizontally and make S.No, Id and Address whole column fixed. I am unable to think of css or js that will go into this. I would be higly grateful if anybody can help.

UPDATE:

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6txc8dLb/

Comment: Could you add a fiddle to help...

Comment: I like your text table, you should just use that ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix columns in horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826775/fix-columns-in-horizontal-scrolling)

Comment: @GopalkrishnaNarayanPrabhu Updated

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 3
        }
    } );
} );
```

```css
    th, td { white-space: nowrap; }
    div.dataTables_wrapper {
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>5421</td>
                <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td>8422</td>
                <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: doesnt work if i need both fixed columns and fixed headers

Answer (score 2):

@Kartikey, here is a link to a [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/IT0niFkgfv) that will give you a working start. I've used a CSS property called `sticky`. What this does is positions an element relative to anything on the document and once it is scrolled past a certain point in the viewport, it fixes the position of the element, which can be specified by using properties like `top`, `bottom`, `right`, or in your case `left`.

Consider reading more on the position property in this [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/).

CSS Code:

```
.freeze {
    position: sticky;
    left: 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: `sticky` is a great position attribute. This seems to work for a single column, but how does it work for multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

try using this in your css file

```
th:first-child,
td:first-child  {
position: sticky;
left: 0px;
z-index: 100;
background: #fff;
```

Answer (score -3):

This should do the trick in normal html/css:

```
<th style="width: (some value);"></th>
```