# How can I do a scroll inside my table?

Tags: html, css, scroll, html-table

I'm trying to do some similar to Excel's sheets in HTML, but it's not working. The idea is to fix some column of my table and put a scroll in the rest of the other columns. I was looking for help and saw some comment saying to put two tables inside one bigger table. I'll show my example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>How can I do a Scroll in a specific part of my screen?</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="maindiv">
        <table id="maintable">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th id="colfixed">
                        <table id="fixedtable">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th> Name </th>                         
                                </tr>                                   
                                <tr>
                                    <td> Person 1 </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> Person 2 </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> Person 3 </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </th>
                    <th id="colscroll">
                        <table id="scrolltable">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th> Day 1 </th>
                                    <th> Day 2 </th>
                                    <th> Day 3 </th>                                                            
                                </tr>                                   
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 1 </td>
                                    <td> 1 </td>
                                    <td> 1 </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 1 </td>
                                    <td> 1 </td>
                                    <td> 1 </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> 1 </td>
                                    <td> 1 </td>
                                    <td> 1 </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

The point is: I would like to have people's names always visible, and a side scroll for the days' columns (this example shows 3 days, but I'll probably have more than 100 days). Basically that's it. If you guys know any better HTML structure to do that, or if there is some CSS property that might do this I'll be really glad to know!

(I was trying to use some `overflow: scroll` and `border-collapse: collapse`, but it didn't work as I expected).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix columns in horizontal scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826775/fix-columns-in-horizontal-scrolling)

Comment: One which HTML elements were you using `overflow` and `border-collapse`?

Comment: Can you also please post the CSS you are using for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at `position:sticky` *and its polyfills(to support obsolete browsers)* : https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

[CSS demo](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JZoLzN) (**no need to imbricate tables**, a single table will do):

```css
div {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative
}

tr> :first-child {
  background: gray;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>day</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>person</th>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>person</th>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>person</th>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>person</th>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>person</th>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: codepen demo screenshot]

Comment: explain downvote , thank you ! (doesn't work, question misunderstood, not about css, else ...)